# Flatten mesh with no distortion

Tags: uv, geometry

I am using Blender as the basic 3d tool to design the paper craft (like origami, but with die-cut). 
My question is that is it possible for me to flatten the mesh with the polygon undistorted? So that I can print it out on paper and reconstruct the 3d model.

Comment: wow. and i also answered that one. *face palm*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question, it seems the [Export Paper Model](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Paper_Model) would do it fully automatically. Related [Blender Artists thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?186071-Export-Paper-Model).

This addon will export an SVG of the flattened model.

[image]

It works well for most shapes, you even get extra flaps for sticking. Note the outward surfaces will generally not overlap, if there is overlapping it is only the stick-lips.

This:

[image]

becomes this:

[image]