# How to unwrap a model in 3d viewport (not UV unwrap)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a model that looks like this

[image]

I want to unwrap it along the seam to be used for further modelling in the viewport. I want to unwrap it and re-wrap onto another cylinder of bigger radius. I think its a simple step but all my searches are leading to UV unwrapping.

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:
The above shape is obtained by intersection of two cylinders and then using a boolean modifier as shown below. So I can't use proportional editing on a plane to get that exact shape.
[image]

and finally I want to unwrap the shape and rewrap it along the bigger circle as shown below
[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28678/2843, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2351/2843

Comment: I fail to understand how this solves my problem. But its a wonderful addon. Thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: You just get answers as good as your question is ;-)

Comment: Ok so now you mention you're using a boolean modifier. Could you please tell us what do you mean by "re-wrap onto this" ? The result would look like the "inside" tube scaled larger and offset on x and y ?

Comment: There wouldn't be any scaling. The result would look like an incomplete cylinder(like a "C" shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me using the mentioned [Export Paper Model](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Paper_Model) AddOn. So that was more than just a helpful hint ;-)

[image: Example of deformed Mesh]

Pretty straight forward:

1. Just assign this single Seam on the "front" of your Mesh
   *(You don't need all these Seams at the top/bottom)*
2. Then export via the AddOn with **Limit Island Size** being active for it to work
3. Note down the Scale that the AddOn uses in the bottom left Settings Area of your File Browser and Export the SVG to a known location. You can uncheck *Create Tabs* and *Create Numbers*.
4. Import the SVG back again via *File* - *Import*
   *(it will be two Curves, you just need the black one and you can remove the material, I used the "vertical Lines" here for demonstration purposes)*
5. Scale the Model back up with the Size you wrote down above
   *You probably need to reposition it's origin - and make sure to always Apply Scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*
6. Position your Curve Object properly along the X-Axis standing Upright in the Z-Direction
7. Add a Curve Modifier with your desired "base curve" that it should wrap along to the imported Curve et voilà...
   *Optionally you can now reposition it along the X-Axis if needed or convert your Curve to a Mesh <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*

Comment: It works! Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 4):

I may be mistaken but I think you've gone a complicated way. It is less trivial to make a plane follow a curve than the opposite.

I propose you start with a plane instead.

1. Create a plane Scale it on X axis by 10 [image][image]
2. Enter edit mode (tab) and select the top and bottom edges
3. Subdivide by 40 (spacebar then search for Subdivide)[image]
4. Enable proportional edit mode (see screenshot) and select two vertices[image]
5. Move the upwards and while moving, use your mouse wheel to increase the proportional editing falloff
6. Exit edit mode and rotate the plane by 90° on X axis
7. Create a circle (shift+a, curves > circle) and scale it by 400% (that's just an example)
8. Make sure the circle is at coordinates 0, 0, 0
9. Select the plane and add a modifier called Curve [image]
10. In the modifier, select the circle You should now see the plane wrapping around the circle[image]
11. Adjust the scale of the plane to do a full revolution (here scale at 12.56)[image]

And with this you're done. You can then apply the Skin modifier to the plane to give some depth. You can duplicate the plane the circle and make a smaller inner tube. There are many possibilities this way.

UV texturing is pretty easy too.

Comment: In the proportional editing mode, select another curve than what I selected to have a mesh similar to what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) but that may not solve my problem :/ Maybe my question wasn't clear. I've edited the question. Please look at it.

Comment: In the step 4: How do you know how to move the vertices to end up with a precise shape? You just eyeball it? Not exact.

Comment: of course you eyeball it, the question wasn't clear initially.